# ¿Cómo puedo operar los números introducidos en un <input> directamente en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que pretendo es coger los números de un `<input>` y posteriormente operarlos directamente desde JavaScript:

Si por ejemplo en el  `<input>` se introduce `((2+2)/4)*3` que la respuesta sea: `3`

---

Solución basándome en las respuestas recibidas e concluido la siguiente solución a la pregunta:

Javascript:

```
function calc() {

    //Coger el valor del input
    var value = document.getElementById("value").value;

    //Operar los datos recogidos
    var operation = eval(value); 

        //Mostrar el resultado
        alert(operation); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <input id="value" type="number">
    <button id="calculate" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola @Javi, deberías dejar también el problema inicial en tu pregunta ya que si no las respuestas dejan de tener validez para la misma. Para eso sirve agregar una respuesta como aceptada, para indicar a los usuarios la respuesta que te ha resuelto tu duda. En caso de que utilizaras otra respuesta distinta, en ese caso deberías de responder con tu propia respuesta a tu pregunta. Un saludo :)

Comment: Gracias @Error404 lo tendré en cuenta!

Comment: Deberías de realizarlo también en esta pregunta ya que si te fijas ahora mismo carece de enunciado y por tanto de validez para el resto de usuarios ya que no se muestra el problema original.

Comment: Si, de hecho ahora lo estoy editando

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Listo! Ya está corregido

Comment: Mariano creo que te has equivocado, puede que tengan relación entre sí, pero no son tan iguales como para marcarlo como duplicado.

Comment: No es lo mismo porque yo no pretendo hacer nada en tiempo real y tampoco que estén sincronizados el js con PHP, además creo que algún usuario que tenga una duda de este tipo le aclarara mucho más las cosas esta pregunta que esa otra para hacer algo sencillo

Comment: @Javi El evento que se dispara puede cambiar, pero el método es el mismo. Y como se muestra en las respuestas, se le recomienda no utilizar PHP, sino resolverlo directamente con JavaScript. Para que una publicación sea duplicada, se considera que tienen respuestas idénticas, independientemente de la pregunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías recoger el valor directamente del input y usar la función `eval`.

```
var tuInput = document.getElementById("tuInput");
var operacion = tuInput.value;
var suma = eval(operacion);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Funciona bien gracias

Comment: Éste es el gran peligro de `eval`: evaluar entradas sin sanearlas antes. Debes tener muchísimo cuidado con dónde y cómo usas código como éste porque puede acarrear problemas de seguridad.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Si, por supuesto habrá que realizar una comprobación para validar que los datos que se quieren evaluar son correctos. Gracias por recalcar este punto. Yo no lo había añadido porque creo que cada uno debería de utilizar las validaciones que correspondan con su código.

Comment: Es cierto lo que decís, pero el uso que le voy a dar a 'eval()' es solamente para operaciones realizadas en el navegador y no en el servidor, es decir, es para hacer simples cálculos, lo uso como iniciativas mías para aprender cosas nuevas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el constructor [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

```js
var sumar = document.getElementById("sumar").value;
console.log(new Function('return ' + sumar)());
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sumar" value="(2+2)/2">
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación también Aldanux!

Comment: Nunca he usado este método antes, pero parece que potencialmente podría tener los mismos problemas de seguridad que `eval`.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - Es cierto es similar al `eval()` (evil) pero en este caso no tiene peligro ninguno.